# Denoiser messing up final render

Tags: rendering, denoise

I have a problem with the denoiser, I need it but it's messing up final render.
Everything seems right.
[image: This it's the image before denoiser]

Then when denosier comen in.

[image]

Presets are default and this is the first time this happens,  image its 1920x1080 with 512 tiles at a 1080ti.

I have volumetric scatter at .1

I gave up. Final result: [image]

That´s at 5048 samples, denoiser radius 1 and turned off volumetrics, it lasted a lot, about 1/2 hour but i'll leave like that, thank's for the comments.

Comment: Denoising is not magic, it needs something way less noisy than your input to give proper results ; so first, increase the samples. If the denosing keeps destructing the details, try lowering it's Radius.

Comment: Ok, im at 1024 samples, ill try something higher ill

Comment: Whoa - You're at 1024 samples and this is your result??? You should be getting way better imagery than this (unless you're after a heavily stylistic look), but it depends on several factors: largely, lighting and material choices. Are you sure the scene needs volumetric lighting? You could fake results in the compositor using far less render time and smoother results.

Comment: I think i'm turning off volumetrics and getting windows off, i am at 10000 samples and getting a slight better result, but it's the same almost.

Comment: Volumetrics will always make images much noisier. So be ready to increase the samples by a lot.